# No account password is required to obtain the data table structure

Tags: database, metadata

Is there a method to extract the structure of data tables in a database without requiring a database account password? This issue arose when I tried Amundsen's ingestion service.

I really look forward to your answer to this question. If you provide an answer, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Not if they care about security.   Also, there are many different database engines, so you should edit your question to list the platform you are talking about.

Comment: For example, MySQL or PostgreSQL, I know the IP address and port number (such as 3306) that provide this service, but I don't know its account and password. Is there any way to extract its data table structure (or metadata)?